# NodeJS : Socket.IO : Websocket request is showing status as finished instead of expected 101

Tags: node.js, azure, websocket, socket.io

I have a Node JS application which implements socket.io. The application works perfectly hosted on during testing. However, when deployed to Azure Apps, it starts to misbehave.
Upon analyzing the requests, I observed two differences.

1. The websocket request is sent as ws://localhost:3000/... from localhost while when on Azure Apps it's sent as wss://azure-apps-url/...
2. The websocket request has a HTTP status of 101 when on localhost and "(finished)" when deployed.

NOTE: My azure application has websockets enabled.

I am not able to figure out what could be the issue. Any help would be appreciated. Do let me know if application code is required to debug the issue.

Edit: Added Code upon request.
**Server Side Code:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var ExpressPeerServer = require('peer').ExpressPeerServer;
var options = {
    debug: false
}
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use('/peerjs', ExpressPeerServer(server, options));
```

**Client Side Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//localhost:3000 to be replaced by Azure Site URL
var socket = io.connect("localhost:3000");
var peer = new Peer({host: "localhost", port: "3000", path: "/peerjs"});

//further operations with peer and socket
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating `server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);` to `server.listen(process.env.port);` seems to have resolved the issue. However, the socket connections still don't work. I am assuming the implementation of PeerJS and Socket.IO both could be causing some sort of conflict.